# Android Studio 2.0,Emulator showing malformed multiple screen with api less than 14

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio 2.0 have bug with below api 14

[image: Api 11-13]

with Android Studio 2.0, I can't even test my app...Emulator is not work properly.
How to solve this problem or how to run emulator with below 14 api without this bug...???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this create a new AVD and select a Nexus Device first then change the Android version below api 14 say Gingerbread then start the AVD, will solve the issue, i think the issue is with dpi levels. If you select ldpi screen resolution this problem comes.